# Influxdb - best practice for adding columns to database that is constantly evolving

Tags: influxdb

I have a rawdata import from a data source which I store in a raw data measurement.

I then build a host of features on top of this data. This list of features stored in the next table is constantly evolving.

What is best practice for implementing this in Influxdb?

Because I am constantly thinking of new columns or fields to add I can’t decide the best way to implement it.

Comment: If the list of features is only growing then there's no problem extending the list of fields since you are not locked to a schema. You may consider grouping fields into different tables if it makes sense. Removing fields can be a bit tricky though.
Can you be a bit more specific in what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I suppose though what I’m wondering is imagine I import a measurement with two fields two tags. Then the next time I go to import I think ah I should have added two extra fields. Is there any way I can add the two columns? Or do I need to redo the table?

Comment: You can insert any set of fields(columns) as long as the type of the data is the same within corresponding fields. It doesn't matter if you have all, some, or even new fields in the datapoints you're inserting. Needless to say if you add data with new columns later, previous datapoints will just not have any values for those new fields. You can backfill the data if it is available but you don't have to. In any case no explicit, additional action is required for new fields. A thing that you'd want to consider is what should be field and what should be tag.

Comment: But to address your question directly, you don't have to redo the table, you just insert the data as you did before just with additional fields, and the new fields will be added.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your time